# Add fragments into a Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity that contains a FrameLayout. I use the following code to add Fragments to the Fragment Activity.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, fargmentTag);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

Now R.id.fragment_content is FrameLayout. This adds a Fragment onto the view. But the underlying view still remains visible. Meaning the one lying view is seen through the new fragment ? What am i doing wrong.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the next fragment use `ft.replace();` so the previous one will be repalced.

Answer (score 1):

Either `ft.remove()` the old fragment, or use `ft.replace()` instead of `ft.add()`.

Answer (score 1):

ft.replace() should work fine, otherwise you have to update your question for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Using ft.replace  will replace any previously added fragment with this fragment but if the activity has some view added to its layout rather than a fragment ,then the fragment added through add or replace will show its content over it rather than replacing it as it is not a fragment.
either add another layout within your main layout and assign it some id and then add the fragment to that container.
Hope it helps.